# can't close my bootstrap $uibModalInstance and its value is undifind

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularjs with bootstap

modal controller :

```
'use strict';
angular.module('users').controller('userModelController',
        [ '$scope', 'row', function($scope, row, $uibModalInstance) {
            $scope.row = row;

            $scope.cancel = function($uibModalInstance) {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        },

        ]);
```

controller code to open my window

```
this.openUser = function(row) {
                                $scope.row = row;
                                var userInstance = $uibModal
                                .open({
                                    animation : $scope.animationsEnabled,
                                    templateUrl : './user_model',
                                    controller : 'userModelController',
                                    backdrop : true,
                                     windowClass: 'monitoring-modal',
                                    resolve : {
                                         row: function () {
                                              return row;
                                            }
                                    }
                                });
                                 userInstance.result.then(function (row) {
                                     $scope.row = row;
                                 });
                            };
```

I am using the popup window to edit table row
now I get the row value in my window but when I click on close to close the window I get that uibModalInstance is undifine

my window

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't injected the modal instance `[ '$scope', 'row','$uibModalInstance', function($scope, row, $uibModalInstance)`

Comment: I tried to inject it, but when I do that I get this error "Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- userModelController"

Comment: **Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- userModelController**

Comment: Unknown provider may be the indicator that you didn't put `angular.module('users', ['ui.bootstrap'])`

Comment: angular.module('Authentication', []);
    angular.module('Home', []);
    angular.module('menuBar',[])
    angular.module('register',[])
    angular.module('register',[])
    angular.module('UserValidation',[])
    angular.module('users',['ui.bootstrap'])
    angular.module('smart-table',[])

Comment: I added it in my app.js

Comment: ya row is get the selected entity value

Comment: are both controllers under the same module

Comment: yes **angular.module('users').controller('usersListController',**  and  **angular.module('users').controller('userModelController',** 
    [

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use `[ '$scope', 'row','$uibModalInstance', function($scope, row, $uibModalInstance)`

In addition in `this.openUser` use: `controller: ['$scope', 'row', '$uibModalInstance']`

`this.openUser = function(row) {
                                $scope.row = row;
                                var userInstance = $uibModal
                                .open({
                                    animation : $scope.animationsEnabled,
                                    templateUrl : './user_model',
                                    controller: ['$scope', 'row', '$uibModalInstance', ''userModelController'],
                                    backdrop : true,
                                     windowClass: 'monitoring-modal',
                                    resolve : {
                                         row: function () {
                                              return row;
                                            }
                                    }
                                });
                                 userInstance.result.then(function (row) {
                                     $scope.row = row;
                                 });
                            };`

Comment: how can I  in this.openUser use: controller: ['$scope', 'row', '$uibModalInstance'] can you explain more please

Comment: check the edited answer, if it doesn't help, can you paste your code in plnkr please? we would be able to help your code.  Thanks!

Comment: I get this error **angular.js:12520 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string**

Comment: this page is part from big application I don't know if I can make it in plnkr

Comment: I tried to paste it on this plnkr but it need some modification to work [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zz9gPVLjHZv9Bls6fngZ?p=preview) sorry but I am new with this technology